# zf2 regex routing

Tags: regex, routes, zend-framework2

I am struggling with regex routing....
The following urls should be valid:

- /shop/api/list
- /shop/api/cart
- /shop/api/login
- /shop/api/details/0123456789

And the **details url, the last one**, is not really cooperating with the following route:

```
            'child_routes' => array(
                'angularlist' => array(
                    'type' => 'Regex',
                    'options' => array(
                        'regex'    => '/api/(?<page>login|cart|list|details(?<id>\/[0-9]+))',
                        'spec' => '/api/%page%[/:%id%]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Shop\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Api',
                            //'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'        => 'list',
                        //  'param'         => '[0-9]',
                        ),
                        /* todo ipv elke child toe te voegen 'route'    => '/api/[:action]', 'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => 'list|details|login|dashboard'
                        )*/
                    ),
                ),
             )
```

Comment: Regex routes are more expensive than Segment routes, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of struggling with less-readable & dirty regex hacks, you can easily implement a [Segment](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment) route stack like below:

```
'shop' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/shop/api',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Shop\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'Api',
            'action'        => 'index'
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes'  => array(
        'angularlist' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/:action[/:id]', // id is optional
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
```